# American English & British English Note Values

Tags: discussion

Depending on the Questioner (And sometimes the Answerer), a mix of [note value terms in both British English and American](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note_value) English exist. Chalk it up to my stubborn American values, but referencing the opposite names sometimes takes much longer than I'd like to admit. **And amazingly, this site has a great mix of people all over the world referencing both forms.**

Is there a standard we should agree to use? (That probably won't go well)

Should questions define the type in answers proceeding?

Could we possibly have an `alt-text` type of reference?

Am I making this out to be a problem more than I should?

Since note values happen so commonly, I didn't [immediately see this answer](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/449/us-english-language-terminology), but it may value a discussion by itself. And I'm not speaking of spelling (easy to parse) but more of special terminology unique to music itself.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting Matthew Read:

> I believe the general SE policy is that any variant of English is OK and shouldn't be changed due to minor spelling or semantic issues. But if something's confusing to the point that it's a concern, I don't see any reason not to edit in some clarification or leave a comment.

I agree with this quote, and it seems like a good way to be accommodating and accepting while also keeping things clear is to let people use whatever words are used in their flavor (flavour) of English, and perhaps edit in clarifications when needed or likely helpful.

So perhaps if we get a question talking about "quavers" and "crotchets", we would A) leave that language in and B) optionally add in parentheses with the alternate English words. So an OP's "*blah blah **quaver** blah blah*" might be edited to read, "*blah blah **quaver (eighth note)** blah blah*".

One thing we could look at doing beyond that might be to have a sticky meta post or something in the help center (centre) of a list of BrE and AmE equivalents, and maybe extending to note names with solfege and letter-names matched up with some common alternatives (e.g., H means B and B means Bb, etc.).

Comment: I'd hate to enforce those who aren't too familiar with the other version to constantly refer to the opposite though. I assume a friendly edit will suffice from a polyglot. Or a custom shortcut tag that automatically offers translations based on browser language settings?

Comment: @ThatWebDude - editing to one specific word would not be friendly to folks from the other side of the pond, so I think Todd's 2 suggestions are the best of both worlds. The glossary idea would be much more helpful with the letter-names he mentions, as there are quite a few standards, not just an American/English clash.

Comment: @DrMayhem, quant à l'idée d'un glossaire, Monsieur Croche dit « Même les durées. » ;^D More seriously, we are getting a fair number of people for whom English is a foreign language, so a Wiki-able stick post of the various forms of various terms is probably a good idea. By all means, edit posts to add the other English variant in parentheses (I do that in my own posts), but some reference for people who don't naturally think in those terms might help.

Comment: For similar efforts, see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/784/14522, http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/16135/14522 and http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/a/37/14522.